# Does Tarski's squaring theorem imply Axiom of Choice in NFU?

Tags: axiom-of-choice, cardinal-arithmetic, new-foundations

I'm trying to see which results from mainstream set theory (ZF) about Axiom of Choice can be proved in New Foundations with Urelements (`U` is added simply because otherwise Axiom of Choice doesn't hold). Currently I'm stuck proving Tarski's theorem, that the claim

"for every infinite set $A$, there exists a bijection between $A\times\{*\}$ and $A\times A$"

implies AC (in fact, Zermelo's wellordering theorem). All the proofs I've seen so far (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_theorem_about_choice#Proof) seem to rely on the existence of Hartogs' ordinal for a given set $X$ (an ordinal so big that there is no injection from it to $X$), but that's obviously not going to work in a theory with universal set, since $V$ doesn't have a Hartogs' ordinal.

I am aware that all I need is one injection from $V$ to $Ord$ (set of all ordinals), but so far it has eluded me. I can't even build it recursively on rank since the universe is not well-founded ($V\in V$).

Does anyone have any ideas on how to proceed? Could it possibly be that the implication doesn't hold?

Comment: Ordinals are not specifically needed, just some set with adequate properties. For example, see this proof I wrote long ago - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56466/for-every-infinite-s-s-s-times-s-implies-the-axiom-of-choice/56575#56575 - That said, I'm not sure such sets necessarily exist in NFU.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, any wellordered (in fact, any "choosable", as your proof shows) set bigger than the one we started with is ok. However, as I said, no such set can exist for $V$.

Comment: @Veky, Yes! It should work in NFU. All the tools for that equivalence are there. You ony need hartogs aleph of $T^2|V|$, if you can well order the set of double singletons you can well order everything. (T.Forster).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure: how exactly does your argument use Tarski's theorem?

Comment: @Veky, you take the Hartog number of the set of all double singletons $\iota^2 V$. Then run Tarski's proof on it. You get to well order $\iota^2 V$. But if you do that, then clearly you can well order every set using Stratified Comprehension!

Comment: @Veky unless you are working in very weak fragments of NFU, generally you cannot have an injection from V to Ord, this is inconsistent with NFU + Infinity and Inconsistent with NF.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Yes, I realized that about injecting V into Ord. But I still can't see how I can be sure there is a Hartogs ordinal for iota2V, while not having one for V itself. Do you want to say that Hartogs usual proof idea works everywhere except for V, or is there something really special about iota2V that makes Hartogs ordinal there possible to exist? Anyway, thank you for all your guidelines!

Comment: @Veky, hmmm... You can stretch Ord by redefining the pair implementation used in the well orderings used in its definition, as to get Ord not strictly subnumerous to Frege 1 (i.e. $\iota V)$. Now let Ord+ mean Ord - Frege 0, then to prove that 1 is well orderable, work with Ord+ instead of the Hartog of 1 in Tarski's argument. In other words, let K= 1 union Ord+, then take f: K \to K x K, and complete Tarski's proof

Answer (score -1):

The proof in $\sf NF$ is pretty much the same as in $\sf ZF$, but one needs to make some adjustments to assure stratification.

First note that if you can well order $\iota^2``V = \{ \iota^2 `x  \mid x \in V \}$, where $\iota^2 ` x  = \{\{x\}\}$, then you can easily well order $V$ via Stratified comprehension. To see that, let $R$ be a well ordering on $\iota^2 ``V$, then we can define a well ordering $R^*$ on $V$, as: $$ R^*= \{ \langle a,b \rangle \mid  \langle \iota^2 `a , \iota^2`b \rangle \in R   \} $$

Now in Forster's book: [Set Theory with a Universal Set: Exploring an Untyped Universe](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/set-theory-with-a-universal-set-9780198514770?cc=us&lang=en&), 2.2 Cardinal and ordinal arithmetic, Remark 2.2.2, Theorems 2.2.3, 2.2.4, pp: 46-48.

To quote [terminology modified], he concludes:

> "that any aleph $ < |Ord| $ is $T^2$ of something, and that $ |Ord|$ itself is  not $T^2$ of anything. The notation '$\aleph(\alpha)$' denotes the least aleph not $\leq \alpha$,  Hartogs' aleph function. Thus $\sf |Ord| \not \leq |\iota^2 ``V|$, and $\sf |Ord| = \aleph (| \iota^2`` V  |)$"

Just to clarify, $|Ord|$ here which is usually denoted as $\Omega$, the order type of $Ord$, cannot be $T^2 \alpha$ for some $\alpha$ because by then $\alpha$ would be an ordinal not in $Ord$. Also $\Omega \not \leq |\iota^2 ``V|$ because if not so, then there will be an injection from $Ord$ to $\iota^2``V$, and a well ordering $R$ on the range of that injection that would be an element of $\Omega$, and so the order type of $R^{\iota^-2} = \{\langle a,b \rangle \mid \ \langle \iota^2 a, \iota^2 b \rangle \in R \}$ would an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\Omega=T^2 \alpha$.

Now, simply you can use $Ord$ itself as the well ordered set to unite with $\iota^2 `` V$, and run Tarski's' argument, to prove the existence of a well ordering on $\iota^2 ``V$.